# Access specific feature property in local GeoJSON file?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I am working with a GeoJSON feature collection file. It has >100 features, each feature has a set of coordinates labelled "geometry" and a set of characteristics labelled "properties". I have been able to display the geometry (polygons) on my map with the following code:

```
var geojsonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'http://myserver.com/mygeojson.js'
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "red",
      lineDash: [4],
      width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
    })
  })
});

geojsonLayer.setZIndex(100);
map_obj.addLayer(geojsonLayer);    // map_obj is the map defined elsewhere.
```

There are some more coordinates stored in the properties of the GeoJSON which I want to access and display, I'm also interested in a couple of other parameters. How do I go about accessing these features in OpenLayers? Or maybe this is not possible with OL and I need to parse it using fetch or something similar?

The file is large, so below I have indcluded just one feature:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              5.785,
              60.497
            ],
            [
              6.026,
              60.502
            ],
            [
              6.103,
              60.584
            ],
            [
              6.137,
              60.748
            ],
            [
              6.093,
              60.83
            ],
            [
              5.971,
              60.827
            ],
            [
              5.833,
              60.742
            ],
            [
              5.785,
              60.497
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "NumIdBirth": 2,
        "CType": 6,
        "LonTrajCellCG": [
          5.9569,
          5.97
        ],
        "CRainRate": 0,
        "ConvTypeMethod": 1,
        "ConvType": 1,
        "SeverityIntensity": 0,
        "ConvTypeQuality": 3,
        "MvtDirection": 299,
        "CTPressure": 60600,
        "NumIdCell": 1,
        "CTReff": 0,
        "LonG": 5.9569,
        "LatTrajCellCG": [
          60.6425,
          60.62
        ],
        "ExpansionRate": 57.384,
        "CTPhase": 1,
        "LatG": 60.6425,
        "BTmin": 268.25,
        "BTmoy": 273.98,
        "CTCot": 23.57,
        "CTCwp": 0.237,
        "NbPosLightning": 0,
        "SeverityType": "",
        "PhaseLife": 2,
        "MvtSpeed": 0.645,
        "Surface": 240,
        "Duration": 900,
        "CoolingRate": -11.2104
      }
    }
```

Comment: GeoJSON object properties are in OL accessible through .`get(propertyName)` method. For example, if your GeoJSON has property named `otherParameter`, you can access it in OL with `geojsonLayer.get('otherParameter')`.

Comment: That's returning undefined.

Comment: Please edit your question and include excerpt from your GeoJSON, showing those additional properties that you want to access.

Comment: I have added a single feature from the feature collection, I'm interested in the values after "properties", in particulat MvtSpeed and LatTrajCellCG and LonTrajCellCG

Comment: I can't even use geojsonLayer.features, which seems odd - maybe it's something to do with the file?

Comment: Okay - I got somewhere trying a new method using JQuery. I loaded the file : `$.getJSON( "http://myserver.com/mygeojson.js", function( data ) {
    console.log(data.features); //json output 
    console.log(data.features[0].properties);
  });` The first log gives as array of 97 objects (ie. each feature). I can then access the properties for one of those objects by using an index. I don't understand why this works, and it doesn't with OL. I will post this as the answer once I get further with the code.

Comment: @TomazicM `geojsonLayer` is not the feature

Comment: What exactly do you want to display where, how and when?

Comment: @bugmenot123 - at this stage I just want to be able to access those three properties and perform a calculation. I have had success displaying the polygon, that's not the issue. For example, I'm interested in the properties "MvtSpeed" and "MvtDirection".

Comment: @Mike Ups, my mistake, of course you are right. So to correct my comment about accessing features, `.get(propertyName)` applies to individual features, not to the whole layer. I apologize for wrong and misleading comment.

Comment: @dwright: For all features? For one feature? For which feature? At page load? At random times? ;)

Comment: @bugmenot123 IMO that's not relevant right now as I'm having trouble accessing properties of a feature. But I'll play ball. Each file has >100 (1 posted in the question) features and each feature has a bunch of properties. I'd like to access 4 of these properties (per feature), perform a calucation which returns 2 coordinates, and plot them on my map. I want this to happen when a tickbox is checked.

Comment: It is very relevant because it depends on the means of accessing the properties! Imagine if you meant that you wanted to access just the properties of a feature that was clicked on vs. doing something with all the geodata in the layer, no matter where.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [forEachFeatureAtPixel](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel) for that. Something like this:

```
var displayFeatureInfo = function (pixel) {
  var feature = map_obj.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
    return feature;
  });  
  if (feature) {
    console.log(feature.get('MvtSpeed'), feature.get('LatTrajCellCG'), feature.get('LonTrajCellCG'));
  }
};
     
map_obj.on('click', function (evt) {
  displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
});
```

[image: demo]

Comment: So for my case, would "map" be my geojsonLayer vector layer? Or my map object?

Comment: Oh, sorry. map would be map_obj. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you - but unfortunetly that does not work for me. Put some console logs in the function and it does not appear to get past `var displayFeatureInfo = function (pixel) {`

Comment: Here is a working demo: https://anatolysukhanov.com/openlayers/1.html (The feature is at https://anatolysukhanov.com/openlayers/data.json)

Comment: Yes, I have had success displaying the polygons. What I am trying to do is extract a few of the properties, perform some calculations and display them.

Comment: Looking at the forEachFeatureAtPixel method again. You say you have a working example, but that just appears to be the json file link - perhaps you meant to post a different link?

Comment: The example is https://anatolysukhanov.com/openlayers/1.html

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using jquery to load the geoJSON to access the properties. Here is the code:

```
$.getJSON( "http://myserver.com/mygeojson.js", function( data ) {

  data.features.forEach(dothis);

  function dothis(item){

    console.log(item.properties.MvtSpeed);
    console.log(item.properties.LatTrajCellCG);
    console.log(item.properties.LonTrajCellCG);

  }

});
```

It's a shame I had to do it that way (its a lot more work to now manipulate these properties than using OL), but the option suggested by @Anatoly Sukhanov didn't work me. Neither did the .get method suggested by @TomazicM.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly from the features in the layer

```
  geojsonLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(dothis);

  function dothis(feature){

    console.log(feature.get('MvtSpeed'));
    console.log(feature.get('LatTrajCellCG'));
    console.log(feature.get('LonTrajCellCG'));

  }
```

Note that if doing this at the start of the application you must wait for the source to load

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get errors? Do you get bad results?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use layer's source `addfeature` event handler to access features as they are loaded:

```
geojsonLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function(feature) {
  console.log(feature.get('MvtSpeed');
});
map_obj.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

Comment: It is the source's event `geojsonLayer.getSource().on`

Comment: Thanks, I'm really getting sloppy. Corrected.

Comment: The event type is 'addfeature'.

Comment: geojsonLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function(e) {
 console.log(e.feature.get('MvtSpeed'));
});

Comment: Corrected. This happens, when one doesn't test answer before publishing it.